# Does the phrase "uphold the law" imply "obeying the law"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

The different dictionaries I looked at define "uphold" as meaning to "support or defend or maintain" something.

When I think about that word I think about it being used in the phrase "upholding the law".

For example, a police officer might "uphold the law" by stopping someone from breaking a law or arresting someone who has broken it. Or a judge might "uphold the law" by indicting someone who was charged with breaking it.

Does the word "uphold" in this phrase imply that they also comply with the law/do what it says?

Comment: Philosophically, can you uphold the law if you’re breaking it?

Comment: No definitely not, but I'm wondering if the "semantic" meaning of the word includes "to comply with / obey", or if it has a more narrow meaning (like "defending" by doing job if you're a cop or judge)...

Comment: No, it doesn't. A police officer or judge upholds the law *when other people break it* but might not be law-abiding citizens themselves: IOW hypocrites.

Comment: "The Law" is not a single entity. One may uphold some laws and still break others.

Comment: I think that the expression "upholding the law" often has as its main sense "enforcing the law"—but the term is elastic (or ambiguous) enough to encompass at least some instances where the primary sense is indeed "obeying the law." I haven't researched this, however, and so can't offer real-world examples where the main meaning is clearly one in some cases and the other in others.

Comment: In the U.S. judicial context, of course, "upholding the law" means something else again when applied to a specific law : "finding [a particular] law constitutional in a case in which an adverse party has challenged its validity."

Comment: You would think one implied the other, wouldn't you?

Comment: [EDRI](https://edri.org/our-work/you-cant-uphold-the-law-by-breaking-the-law/) agrees with @Jim: 'Due process starts with respecting the law. Or in other words: you can’t uphold the law by breaking it.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some definitions of *uphold*:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uphold)
>
> - to defend or keep a principle or law,
> - or to say that a decision that has already been made, especially a legal one, is correct
> - to defend or maintain a principle or law,
> - or to state that a decision that has already been made, esp. a legal one, is correct
> - to state that a decision which has already been made, especially a legal one, is correct

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uphold)
>
> - to give support to
> - to support against an opponent

> [FindLaw](https://dictionary.findlaw.com/definition/uphold.html)
>
> - to judge valid
> - let stand [ an award]
>   specifically: to hold constitutional

> [Longman Law Topic](https://www.ldoceonline.com/Law-topic/uphold)
>
> - to defend or support a law, system, or principle so that it continues to exist
>   “a committee that aims to uphold educational standards”
> - if a court upholds a decision made by another court, it states that the decision was correct

The overall sense of *uphold* is thus that of defending, maintaining, asserting, supporting or validating principles, laws and decisions.

None of the definitions deals with or implies anything about the personal morality of those who *uphold*. The nearest to this is the Cambridge *keep a principle or law*, which is sufficiently vague or ambiguous that we might assume *keep...*" to mean *"retain ..."* rather than *"adhere to ..."*

I therefore suggest that upholding a law gives only weak grounds to expect that the upholder will adhere to it. It is quite possible for a person to uphold and profess the general right to property while benefitting personally from fraudulently obtained goods. How otherwise can they hope to retain their ill-gotten gains?

We see the same discussion within politics: It is commonplace to surmise (or discover) that politicians who uphold laws do not themselves obey them. Here is but one example:

> [The Conversation](https://theconversation.com/why-leaders-breaking-rules-is-a-far-more-serious-attack-on-our-liberty-than-lockdown-itself-139405)
>
> "At a time when many Britons would have loved to follow their instincts but followed the government instructions, this message from the prime minister sounded to some like the rules apply only when he says so and he is free to make exceptions for those close to him."

Answer (score 0):

There are two ambiguities in this question. First, ***the** law* in the phrase *uphold the law* can stand for the **specific** law in question (say a particular provision of a particular statute) or for the legal system **as a whole**. Second, when the OP asks whether 'the word "uphold" in this phrase imply that they also comply with the law' this can be taken as asking whether it implies that they comply with it **in the very act** of upholding it, or whether it implies that they comply with it **at other times**. Combining these two ambiguities gives us four questions, with the following answers.

**(1)** Does saying that somebody upholds a specific law on a particular occasion imply that the person complies with that specific law at other times? **No**, as already explained by Anton.

**(2)** Does saying that somebody upholds a legal system as a whole on a particular occasion imply that the person complies with the system's requirements at other times? **No**, but the person's disregarding the requirements very frequently may lead one to think that the act of upholding was disingenuous.

**(3)** Does saying that somebody upholds a specific law on a particular occasion imply that the person complies with it on that occasion? **No**, because the occasions for upholding and the occasions for complying are normally different.

**(4)** Does saying that somebody upholds a legal system as a whole on a particular occasion imply that the person complies with the system's requirements on that occasion? **Yes**, assuming that the act of upholding is an official act. An act of a police officer, judge, etc. wouldn't amount to upholding the legal system if it hadn't been performed in accordance with the system's rules regulating the conduct of police officers, judges, etc.

Comment: I think (3) has to be ***Yes***, but it could allow that they still might break the law on other occasions.